# Creating a method or scope to show lower prices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm confused on how I should make this scope or method. I have the following associations:

Models

```
class User
  has_many :prices
  has_many :products, :through => :prices
  has_many :subscriptions, :foreign_key => :subscriber_id
end

class Product
  has_many :prices
  has_many :users, :through => :prices
end

class Price
  # Table columns => :product_id, :cost, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :store
  has_many :subscriptions, :as => :subscribable
end

class Subscription
  # Table columns => :product_id, :cost, :subscriber_id, :subscribable_id
  # :subscribable_type
  belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :subscribable, :polymorphic => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :subscribable_id, :scope => 
                        [ :subscriber_id, :subscribable_type]
end
```

So the method should be something like:

```
class Price

def self.lower_price
  if self.product_id == self.subscription.product_id
     if self.cost < self.subscription.cost
     end
  end
end

end
```

What this method is suppose to do is show only lower prices of `UserProducts` that belong  to the same `Product` as the `Subscription`, while comparing itself to the subscriptions `price` field to see if its lower.

Am I doing this right? What needs to be fixed?

---

**EDIT**

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_product, lambda { |product_id| where( :product_id => product_id) }
  scope :cheaper, lambda { |cost| where(["prices.cost < :cost", { :cost => cost } ] ) }
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base

  def cheaper_prices
    Price.for_product(product_id).cheaper(cost)
  end
end

PrivatePagesController:

def watch
 @prices = Price.cheaper_prices.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20).order('purchase_date DESC')
end

This gives me the error:

NoMethodError in PrivatePagesController#watch

undefined method `cheaper_prices' for #<Class:0x6f99210>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that you are making a web site where users enter prices they found and subscribe to find cheaper prices.  I'd rename the UserProduct entity to Price.

It's ambiguous whether subscribers subscribe to a product or to a price.  If you clear that up, it may simplify away the polymorphic association.  Let's say that they subscribe to a product with a given price.  Then you want the following:

```
class Price
  # Table columns => :product_id, :price, :user_id
  belongs_to :finder, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :store

  scope for_product, lambda { |product_id| where(:product_id => product_id)
  scope cheaper, lambda { |price| where([ "prices.price < :price", {:price => price} ] }
end

class Subscription
  # Table columns => :product_id, :price, :subscriber_id
  belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :product
  validates_uniqueness_of :subscribable_id, :scope => 
                        [ :subscriber_id, :subscribable_type]

  def cheaper
    Price.for_product(product_id).cheaper(price)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm also confused how on to go about this. I had to duplicate the `UserProduct`( or `Price`) attributes so then it knows how to check for cheaper prices. Since the `Subscription` and `Price` have the same fields, I think I can just compare these 2 models. So the `Subscription` would be compared to all the `Prices`.

Comment: Also, you are correct about my website. The users have to enter new prices. I changed the model to be `Price` instead so it makes since now and in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Yes.  At first I didn't notice that the Subscription entity had a price field.  I'd assume that somewhere in your UI, you will get the subscription.  My other approach was to have the Price model have the method to return the cheaper prices.  Basically, with the scopes given in this answer, any object which can provide the product id and a price can use the scopes.

Comment: I don't understand why this is giving me a `undefinded method` error. I change my model to `Price` and the attribute to `:cost` instead and the users subscribes to the `Price`. I edited my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: The way I described it in the answer, cheaper is a method of a subscription object.  So you need the subscription object, and then call cheaper on it.  What does the code calling cheaper look like?

Comment: I edited my question to show the call that calls `:cheaper`. Also, am I suppose to use your other answer? If I am, that would explain why it's not working.

Comment: You are calling cheaper_prices from the Price class as a class method, but the cheaper_prices method is defined in the Subscription class as an instance method.  You can move the def to the Price class, but in order to call it from a price or subscription, you will need the object which has the cost and product_id data.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should name your UserProduct table to be more meaningful.  I cannot tell what it's semantics are except as a linking table.

There is also some confusion about subscribing to a Product or a UserProduct.  I see the polymorphic association, but I suspect there is some confusion.

I notice Subscription has a product_id, so that tells me Subscription belongs to Product, rather than, or in addition to, belongs to subscribable.

So, first you may need to clean up your design.

However, assuming I can take your condition on faith that its what you want, what you would want in SQL is

```
SELECT cheaper.*
FROM user_products
  INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscribable_type = 'UserProduct'
                           AND subscriptions.subscribable_id = user_products.id
  INNER JOIN user_products cheaper ON cheaper.product_id = subscriptions.product_id
WHERE cheaper.price < user_products.price
```

This would give you a report of all the cheaper prices you will find overall.  For all the cheaper prices of a given user_products record, you need to include a condition that it's for a given id.

Next, to make this work in ActiveRecord, we want the select to be on the table for the class, so let's transform the SQL to

```
SELECT user_products.*
FROM user_products
  INNER JOIN subscriptions ON user_products.product_id = subscriptions.product_id
  INNER JOIN user_products target ON subscribable_type = 'UserProduct'
                           AND subscriptions.subscribable_id = target.id
WHERE user_products.price < target.price
  AND target.id = ?
```

Now we're ready to make the ActiveRecord call.

I don't know if ActiveRecord can form joins from an association.  I know the Rails 2.3 API required a string.  So, the scope would be:

```
 class UserProduct
   ...

   #defines UserProduct.cheaper(user_product_id)
   scope :cheaper, lambda do |user_product_id|
     join(%Q{INNER JOIN subscriptions
             ON user_products.product_id = subscriptions.product_id
             INNER JOIN user_products target
             ON subscribable_type = 'UserProduct'
             AND subscriptions.subscribable_id = target.id}).
    where("cheaper.price < user_products.price").
    where(["target.id = :target_id", { :target_id => user_product_id } ] )
  end

  #defines user_product.cheaper
  def cheaper
    UserProduct.cheaper(id)
  end
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can assume that every product you have, has subscription than this should work for you

```
  scope :lower_priced_user_products, self.joins("join subscriptions on subscriptions.product_id = user_products.product_id").where("user_products.product_id < subscriptions.product_id")
```

this will return a read only record. if you want read/write access then you should reload the record using UserProduct.find(rec.id).

let me know how it goes.